# Transactions in Spring kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to use executeInTransaction to publish the messages into kafka in Spring kafka. But i am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TransactionalIdAuthorizationException: Transactional Id authorization failed.
```

I have set the transaction id prefix to producer factory.

```
kafkaProducerFactory.setTransactionIdPrefix("my.reconTxn.");
```

Comment: This is a question for the Kafka folks; it has nothing to do with Spring. Do you have write access to the topics/partitions? The `Authorization` section of [KIP-98](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging) has some information: `Additionally, the AddPartitionsToTxn API requires Write access to the topics corresponding to the included partitions...`

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have write access to the topic and could produce messages without using transactions( using send method).